# keywords matching of list elements with pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have list of elements as:

```
 A=  ['loans','s-class','veyron','trump','rihana','drake','election']
```

I also have another pandas dataframe `B` with columns `category` and `words` which is comma seperated string as:-

```
category              words
audi                  a4, a6
bugatti               veyron, chiron
mercedez              s-class, e-class
dslr                  canon, nikon
apple                 iphone,macbook,ipod
finance               sales,loans,sales price
politics              trump, election, votes
entertainment         spiderman,thor, ironmen
music                 beiber, rihana,drake
........              ..............
.........             .........
```

All I want to map elements of list `A` with column `words` and assign corresponding `category` into a new list.So, expected output would be.

```
matched_categories=['finance','mercedez','bugatti','politics','music','music','politics']
```

Comment: You can select a row like this `df[df['words'].str.contains('loans')]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) for select first matched value:

```
#if always matched all values
matched_categories = [df.loc[df['words'].str.contains(x), 'category'].iat[0] for x in A]
print (matched_categories)
['finance', 'mercedez', 'bugatti', 'politics', 'music', 'music', 'politics']
```

More general solution if some value is not matched - then return `not matched` value:

```
#added last aaa value
A = ['loans','s-class','veyron','trump','rihana','drake','election','aaa']

matched_categories = [next(iter(df.loc[df['words'].str.contains(x),'category']),'not matched')
                      for x in A]
print (matched_categories)
['finance', 'mercedez', 'bugatti', 'politics', 'music', 'music', 'politics', 'not matched']
```

Comment: @Mavrick - There is problem some value not match, need second solution - it is like last value of list `aaa`

Comment: @Mavrick - You can add `matched_categories = [x for x in matched_categories if x != 'not matched']` to the end.

Comment: @Mavrick - Is ordering important?

Comment: @Mavrick - Hmmm, is possible create new quetion for reference to this one? Because still edit question is not recommended in StackOveflow.

Comment: @Mavrick - Also seems expected ouptu should be different, if ascending iorder.

Comment: @Mavrick - Sure, solution will be rewritten.

Comment: It will be so thankful if you provide me one for that solution